# insert image in word with ironpython

Tags: image, ms-word, ironpython

I am looking for a way to insert an image into a word file in ironpython.
i figured out how to replace text by calling the clr module and adding the reference microsoft.office.interop.word however i was not able to write an image to the word document.
what i was working with:

```
import sys
import clr
import System
from System import DateTime
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word")
import Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word as Word

def doc_replace_text(source_filename, tokens, values, destination_filename):

   missing = System.Type.Missing
   replaceAll = Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll

   word_application = Word.ApplicationClass()
   word_application.visible = False

   document = word_application.Documents.Open(source_filename)

   for i in range(len(tokens)):
    for r in document.StoryRanges:
        print "i = %d, tokens[i] = %s, values[i] = %s" % (i, tokens[i], values[i])
        r.Find.Text = tokens[i]
        r.Find.Replacement.Text = values[i]
        r.Find.Wrap = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue
        r.Find.Execute(missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, replaceAll, missing, missing, missing, missing)

   document.SaveAs(destination_filename)
   document.Close()
   document = None

   word_application.Quit()
   word_application = None
```

I'd appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

i figured it out somehow...

```
    clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word")
    from Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word import ApplicationClass
    word=ApplicationClass()
    word.Visible=False
    docPublic=word.Documents.Add()
    mod=docPublic.InlineShapes.AddPicture(path+name+".jpg", False, True,  docPublic.Paragraphs[1].Range)
    mod.Height=200
    mod.Width=300
    docPublic.SaveAs(tpath+name+"_Simulation_Report_Public.docx")
    docPublic.Close()
    docPublic=None
    word.Quit()
    word=None
```

however now i need to place the picture to some other position. i think this could be done by using the shape stuff...

any help would be great

edit: seems i don't have any idea what i'm doing...
from msdn.microsoft.com the AddPicture method takes the values:
FileName, LinkToFile, SaveWithDocument, Left, Top, Width, Height, Anchor

Answer (score 0):

I'm way late to the party, but I was able to place an image at a defined bookmark via defining the bookmark name in Item and then it's location in AddPicture.

```
loc = doc.Bookmarks.Item("BookMarkName").Range
pic = doc.Bookmarks.Item("BookMarkName").Range.InLineShapes.AddPicture(path+name+".jpg",False,True,loc)
```